# custom sort for an array of timezone offsets

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am attempting to sort an array of timezone offsets that looks like the following:

`["+03:00", "-11:00", "+05:00", "-04:00"]`

This is just a subset of the array. All of the offsets for GMT based timezones are included. The logical ordering would be distance from GMT starting with `-11.00`

So the final correct ordering would be:

`["-11:00", "-04:00", "+03:00", "+05:00"]`

I'd have to use `Array.prototype.sort` here, but I'm not entirely sure what the most effective custom sort function to use here would be. Would it involve breaking the string up into two parts? eg: `-|+` and `offset`, eg: `11, 4, 3, 5` and then comparing those? Is there a way to do it with less processing?

Comment: do you ever have to deal with 'half hour zones'? ie. Darwin/Australia is `+9:30` or are they always whole numbers?

Comment: Do the entries in the array have to be strings? Could they be numbers instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sort function should be

```
function(a, b) { 
    return parseFloat(a.replace(':', '.')) - parseFloat(b.replace(':', '.'));
}
```

basically, change the `:` to a `.` and return the difference in the resulting parsed floats

You can also do the following:

```
function(a, b) { 
    return parseInt(a.replace(':', ''), 10) - parseInt(b.replace(':', ''), 10);
};
```

This would convert the strings to `+/-HHMM` which you can then parse as an integer and still be able to support the not insubstantial number of non whole hour timezones. Though I don't think there's that much performance to be gained

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the timezones always end in `:00` you can simply `parseInt` them:

```
["+03:00", "-11:00", "+05:00", "-04:00"].sort(
    ( a, b ) => (a, 10) > parseInt(b, 10)
);
```

`parseInt` will read a string up until it finds characters that don't look like numbers. For example `parseInt('1a')` returns `1`. Since the first part of `'-11:00'` is a valid number (`'-11'`), parseInt will correctly read it.

Comment: which would fail with non whole hour time zones